# Health Check Type ELB with multiple Load Balancers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Assuming I have two load balancers which point to the same server group but are targeting different services (e.g. web and an internal queue). Both are set to Health Check Type = ELB.

According to the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-maintain-instance-levels.html#replace-unhealthy-instance) if an instance becomes unhealthy it will be terminated and replaced.

What happens if an instance becomes unhealthy in regards to only one of the two ELBs, will it still be terminated and replaced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-add-elb-healthcheck.html

> Note that if you attach multiple load balancers to an Auto Scaling group, all of them must report that the instance is healthy in order for it to consider the instance healthy. If one load balancer reports an instance as unhealthy, the Auto Scaling group replaces the instance, even if other load balancers report it as healthy.